# How to stream read pdf from Googlebook API?

Tags: google-books, google-books-api

I want to use Google Book API for my library app. User can tracks book page, and read the pdf, so I can't redirect my user to Google Book API. If user need to buy book, user can pay to Google Book. Is there a way to do this? Is there any free/paid api that helps me do such thing?

I have read about stream read pdf from internet link. I also read about how to get books from Google Book API. But I only get a way to get link to redirect to google book webpage.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I use Google Books Embedded View, that connect user to the Google Book preview page